# electron: How to remove a menu item from the default menu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, menu, electron

### Goal

I'm trying to remove the `Help` menu from Electron app's menu.

I don't want to `setApplicationMenu` of my own because it's fine to use the default menu except for the help, which points to Electron's own help pages.

### Attempts

I've tried the following ways and failed in each case:

#### Remove the tail item, i.e., the Help

```js
var menu = Menu.getApplicationMenu();
menu.items.pop();
```

#### Make it invisible

```js
var menu = Menu.getApplicationMenu();
for(var i=0; i<menu.items.length; i++) {
    if (menu.items[i].role == 'help') {
       menu.items[i].visible = false;
       break;
    }
}
```

#### Remove the menu

```js
mainWindow.removeMenu();
```

This just doesn't work on macOS with my electron version: 10.1.0.

### Question

What's wrong? Should I create a template instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `Menu.setApplicationMenu` after you modify the default menu

```js
const menu = Menu.getApplicationMenu(); // get default menu

menu.items.find((item) => item.role === "help").visible = false; // modify it

Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu); // set the modified menu
```

**Note**: From my experience, `Menu.getApplicationMenu()` will return `null` if it's called before the app `ready` event

Answer (score 7):

menuItem.visible does not work in Electron 13. Instead, I build a new menu without the Help item.

```
  const menu = Menu.getApplicationMenu()
  const items = menu?.items.filter((item) => item.role !== 'help')
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(items))
```